# geolocation API showing address in local language in android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, android-location

I am newbie for a geolocation apis in android. I am developing an android app majorly based on the geolocation apis. If the user is from the "abc" state then only the user will be able to see the content of the app. Everything is working perfectly but sometimes the geolocation api fetch the "abc" state name in other than english language (local language) due to which the app content are not getting visible. How do i make my application to always fetch the address in english ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Locale.US` when init your Geocoder

Kotlin example:

```kotlin
val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.US)
val location LatLng(38.905996,-77.029787)

val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(
    location.latitude, 
    location.longitude, 
    1
)

println(addresses[0].countryName)
println(addresses[0].locality)
```